# How to filter bot users belong to my app when I listen to member_joined_channel event

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to know when bot user (belongs to my app) is added to private channel , I know member_joined_channel event will fired for all invites in the private channel but I am interested in the event only when my bot user is added to private channel and ignore other invites. Is there any way I can filter?

My app is installed in different workspaces . Bot user id of same app is different for different workspace so I cannot filter by bot user id.

Answer (score 1):

Every time your app is installed into a new workspace it will receive the new tokens along with the new bot user ID for that workspace. If you store that bot user ID you can later filter events for your bot.

Since you also get the team ID with each event you just need to match against the respective bot user ID for that team.

Comment: in case you didn't store the bot user ID upon installation, you can retrieve the bot user id via the auth.test (https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) method